# Is there a benefit to loading inline SVGs instead of using them as img src?

Tags: svg

I have had the idea in my head that loading inline SVGs takes less resources than loading img src files. I'm not sure where I got that idea, so I'm hoping to find out if it's true or not.

Here's my example: Company logo is an SVG. I need to use that logo both in the header, which is on a light background, and also in the footer, which is on a dark background. If I load the SVG in both places as inline code, all I have to do is change the CSS fill color. BUT, I realize that it's a whole block of SVG code twice. I'm not sure if that's any better than loading to PNGs with the logo already those different colors.

How would I even test something like that?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a typical use case for an SVG sprite, where you define the SVG code once and then reuse it. You can use an external file with your icon(s), but it's also possible to place it inline.

Suppose you have this icon:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="60" height="60">
    <path d="M8.017 0a8 8 0 100 16 8 8 0 000-16zm0 2a2 2 0 110 4 2 2 0 010-4zM3.51 6c.016 0 .032 0 .048.002 0 0 3.015.248 4.46.248 1.444 0 4.458-.248 4.458-.248a.5.5 0 01.395.852c-.193.193-.293.182-.426.22a16.18 16.18 0 01-2.428.426c.05 1.877.084 3.307.354 4.2.15.492.297.853.41 1.113.057.13.104.233.143.326.039.092.093.121.093.361a.5.5 0 01-.853.354c-.228-.229-.4-.527-.64-.936a37.549 37.549 0 01-.76-1.371c-.399-.747-.614-1.18-.747-1.443-.132.262-.347.696-.746 1.443-.252.472-.519.962-.76 1.371-.24.409-.412.707-.64.936a.5.5 0 01-.854-.354c0-.24.055-.269.094-.361l.143-.327c.113-.26.26-.62.41-1.113.27-.892.304-2.322.353-4.199-.9-.07-1.517-.235-2.427-.426-.133-.038-.233-.027-.426-.22A.5.5 0 013.51 6z" />
</svg>
```

You can pack it in a zero-sized `<svg>` element, and wrap the icon grafical elements in a `<symbol>` (a template to be rendered elsewhere):

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="logo" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.017 0a8 8 0 100 16 8 8 0 000-16zm0 2a2 2 0 110 4 2 2 0 010-4zM3.51 6c.016 0 .032 0 .048.002 0 0 3.015.248 4.46.248 1.444 0 4.458-.248 4.458-.248a.5.5 0 01.395.852c-.193.193-.293.182-.426.22a16.18 16.18 0 01-2.428.426c.05 1.877.084 3.307.354 4.2.15.492.297.853.41 1.113.057.13.104.233.143.326.039.092.093.121.093.361a.5.5 0 01-.853.354c-.228-.229-.4-.527-.64-.936a37.549 37.549 0 01-.76-1.371c-.399-.747-.614-1.18-.747-1.443-.132.262-.347.696-.746 1.443-.252.472-.519.962-.76 1.371-.24.409-.412.707-.64.936a.5.5 0 01-.854-.354c0-.24.055-.269.094-.361l.143-.327c.113-.26.26-.62.41-1.113.27-.892.304-2.322.353-4.199-.9-.07-1.517-.235-2.427-.426-.133-.038-.233-.027-.426-.22A.5.5 0 013.51 6z" />
    </symbol>
    <!-- ...more symbols as needed -->
</svg>
```

The `viewBox` attribute moves to the `<symbol>` element. Note there is no `fill` defined in this template. The `<svg>` can be an external file (remember to add the `xmlns` attribute), or it can be placed inline anywhere on your HTML page.

Then, you can place an `<svg>` anywhere in the page, and just cite the symbol with a `<use>` element:

```
<svg width="60" height="60"><use href="#logo" /></svg>
```

With an external sprite file, the reference would have to quote the file: `href="path/to/sprite.svg#logo"`. Performance-wise, there is not much of a downside to this approach. The file gets loaded on first use, and on later uses it can be accessed from cache. If you use the icon on several pages, that might even be an advantage, as the cached file is still there across page loads.

`<use>` elements have a default size and position of `x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"`, so all you have to do is give the `<svg>` its proper size. And more important: CSS properties are inherited by the cited symbol, so a `fill` on the `<svg>` will have the same effect as if it was set on the `<symbol>`, but only for the one citation.

All together:

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.container svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container.light {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container.light svg {
    fill: black;
}

.container.dark {
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.container.dark svg {
    fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="logo" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.017 0a8 8 0 100 16 8 8 0 000-16zm0 2a2 2 0 110 4 2 2 0 010-4zM3.51 6c.016 0 .032 0 .048.002 0 0 3.015.248 4.46.248 1.444 0 4.458-.248 4.458-.248a.5.5 0 01.395.852c-.193.193-.293.182-.426.22a16.18 16.18 0 01-2.428.426c.05 1.877.084 3.307.354 4.2.15.492.297.853.41 1.113.057.13.104.233.143.326.039.092.093.121.093.361a.5.5 0 01-.853.354c-.228-.229-.4-.527-.64-.936a37.549 37.549 0 01-.76-1.371c-.399-.747-.614-1.18-.747-1.443-.132.262-.347.696-.746 1.443-.252.472-.519.962-.76 1.371-.24.409-.412.707-.64.936a.5.5 0 01-.854-.354c0-.24.055-.269.094-.361l.143-.327c.113-.26.26-.62.41-1.113.27-.892.304-2.322.353-4.199-.9-.07-1.517-.235-2.427-.426-.133-.038-.233-.027-.426-.22A.5.5 0 013.51 6z" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="container light">
    <svg><use href="#logo"/></svg>
</div>
<div class="container dark">
    <svg><use href="#logo"/></svg>
</div>
```